# How to report bugs in 18.04 Beta

Tags: bug-reporting, 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04 Beta is looking good, but I keep running across a few difficulties related to how they have altered the boot process.

What is best way to report bugs?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted procedure is spelled out here:

[Report a problem in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html)

Excerpt:

> If you notice a problem in Ubuntu, you can file a bug report.
>
> - Type Alt+F2 and type ubuntu-bug nameofprogram
> - If you have a hardware issue or don't know the name of the program affected, just type ubuntu-bug
> - After running one of the above commands, Ubuntu will gather information about the bug. This may take a few minutes. Review the
>     collected information if you wish. Click Send to continue.
> - A new web browser tab will open to continue processing the bug data. Ubuntu uses the website Launchpad to manage its bug reports. If you do
>     not have a Launchpad account, you will need to register for one to
>     file a bug and receive email updates about its status. You can do this
>     by clicking Create a new account.
> - After logging in to Launchpad, enter a description of the problem in the summary field.
> - After clicking Next Launchpad will search for similar bugs in case the bug you are reporting has already been reported. If the bug has
>     already been reported, you can mark that bug as also affecting you.
>     You can also subscribe to the bug report to receive updates about
>     progress with fixing it. If the bug has not already been reported,
>     click No, I need to report a new bug.
> - Fill in the description field with as much information as you can. It's important that you specify three things:
> - What you expected to happen
> - What actually happened
> - If possible, a minimal series of steps necessary to make it happen, where step 1 is "start the program"
> - Your report will be given an ID number, and its status will be updated as it is being dealt with. Thanks for helping make Ubuntu
>     better!